# Using Overwrite for SQL Query Activity on DE for Journey Builder

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio

If a DE is used as the entry for Journey Builder, and that DE is updated daily using an SQL Query in Automation Studio, using the Overwrite option, upon refresh will existing contacts keep re-entering a journey or will they just carry on as they are?

If a Contact was previously in the DE and on the Journey, then they were removed from the DE - are they removed from the Journey, or do they remain on the Journey?

Answer (score 2):

Contacts that will enter the journey and will be overwritten in the DE, will remain in the journey they entered.

When they enter a journey a sort of snapshot of the data that was in the DE is created and data from that snapshot is used in the entire journey.

Keep in mind that overwriting DE data will break "view as a webpage" links in your emails. When an email is opened as a webpage it seems to contain a reference to a specific row in a data extension from which it should pull personalization data - if you remove the row by overwritting data, this link gets broken and the resulting webpage preview of an email has no personalization data.

Comment: Hi @rafal - thanks for your input. Aligns to my understanding generally, however your third paragraph appears to contradict the second paragraph, don't you think?